# How to access variables from one class to another class in PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to get a string from the main window to use in a window triggered with a click. I know how to do it by putting all statements into a single class, but now I'm trying to do the same thing with one class per window. Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.value = QtGui.QLineEdit('23')
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Open Dialog')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.openDialog)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.value)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def openDialog(self):
        self.entry = self.value.text()
        print(self.entry)
        Dialog().exec_()

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=Window):
        super().__init__()

        win = Window()
        self.text = win.entry
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.text)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(hbox)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I'm getting the error "*AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'entry'*" and I don't know any other way to try fix it. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of `Dialog` in the `openDialog` method, so that you can access its attributes directly. That way, the two classes can operate more independently, and you won't need to access the `Window` class from within the `Dialog` class:

```
    def openDialog(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        dialog.label.setText(self.value.text())
        dialog.exec_()
        print(dialog.label.text())

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
win = Window()
self.text = win.entry
```

you declare a new window and accesing its `entry` field but on your window class

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
```

the entry field is not constructed.

So

1. Either you want to create a new window, so you have to put the self.entry on the constructor
2. You want to use the existing window an access its `entry` after calling openDialog

Edit:

Maybe here

```
class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=Window):
        super().__init__()
```

you are initializing the class wrong. The parent constructor should be called with parent=Window too. Then from inside the dialog you could reference the window by doing `self.parent`